# In traditional TeX how to change size of \footnote font?

Tags: footnotes, fontsize, plain-tex

I wonder since `\footnote` works fine in LaTeX when it comes to adapting smaller fontsize, why does the equivalent `\footnote{}` command in traditional TeX not work accordingly? And how do I go about changing the size of footnotes to smaller?

Answer (score 5):

plain tex has no commands to change the size of fonts at all: the body font is always 10pt and the footnotes are similarly a fixed size. If you need fonts at a different size you can of course load them and redefine `\footnote` to use them, but there are no specific declarations to help with that.